# I want to take the name of Player at the end of Android Game using input dialog box from a surface view

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to load the details of player along with High score from the Database

The below code is from SurfaceView class. After reaching endthegame() method, Its able to print below output repeatedly and rest of the code is not reaching

```
 04-03 21:34:55.580 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: REACHED BUILDER DIALOG BOX START
04-03 21:34:55.580 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: THIS IS A TEST FOR BUILDER 0
04-03 21:34:55.581 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: THIS IS A TEST FOR BUILDER 1
04-03 21:34:55.659 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: REACHED BUILDER DIALOG BOX START
04-03 21:34:55.659 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: THIS IS A TEST FOR BUILDER 0
04-03 21:34:55.659 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: THIS IS A TEST FOR BUILDER 1
04-03 21:34:55.696 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: REACHED BUILDER DIALOG BOX START
04-03 21:34:55.696 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: THIS IS A TEST FOR BUILDER 0
04-03 21:34:55.696 7817-8355/androidmydream.myfirstgame I/System.out: THIS IS A TEST FOR BUILDER 1
```

The game is not stopping and i am getting no error in Log. I don't understand whats happening.

```
    public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
    {
    .....    
    public void endthegame()
            {
                System.out.println("REACHED BUILDER DIALOG BOX START");
                if(GamePanel.isGameOver==true) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("THIS IS A TEST for BUILDER");
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
                    builder.setView(view);
                    builder.setTitle("THIS IS A TEST for BUILDER 1");
                    View closeButton =view.findViewById(R.id.close);

                    builder.setTitle("THIS IS A TEST for BUILDER 2");
                    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View clicked) {
                            if (clicked.getId() == R.id.close) {
                                ((Activity) getContext()).finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setTitle("THIS IS A TEST for BUILDER 3");
                    AlertDialog finishDialog = builder.create();
                    finishDialog.show();
                    builder.setTitle("THIS IS A TEST for BUILDER 4");
                }
                System.out.println("REACHED BUILDER DIALOG BOX STOP");
                this.isGameOver=true;
            }
}
```

Getting into the details, The Game Engine has update and draw method in Game Thread. After reaching the LayoutInflater method, the method automatically stopping with out giving any error.

Since it is a Thread, The method update and draw method are calling continously.

Can anyone please tell me why the LayoutInflater method is not invoking and want to know why no error is getting in the Log

Comment: Setting a title on a AlertDialog Builder is a bad way to conduct your debugging. Use `Log.i(TAG, message)` rather.

Comment: It would be useful to see where you are printing the other statements at. It looks like you have some type of infinite loop

Comment: Actually i have provided debugs related to this particular method only. The Application is running remaining debugs also. Can you please tell why with out any error the method is exiting.